# Is there an ANSI Delete Escape Code?

Tags: console

Let's say I have `ABCDEFG` in the console, and I want to remove the `C` (`AB DEFG`).
Is there anyway to do that when the cursor position is currently on the `C`?
Like how `\x1b[2J` clears the console, but only one character instead of the whole console.

***NOTE:*** this is in an stdout pipe.

Anything similar to escape codes works.

Comment: Backspace (above Enter) does not work?

Comment: @dadexix86 no, it needs to work from stdout pipes.

Comment: guessing: control-h? so `\x08`?